# Concatenating various field values for the same ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project where every user has an id and can have multiple regions as follows:

Regions Table

```
ID  | State | etc..
-----------
122 | MD
122 | FL
122 | NY
122 | NJ
122 | CA
11  | NC
11  | SC
11  | GA
```

I would like to essentially write a query that will create a result set where every user ID only appears once and if the user ID is listed multiple times, it concatenates the column as follows...

```
ID  | State
----------
122 | MD, FL, NY, NJ, CA
11  | NC, SC, GA
```

Is this possible? I appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(state SEPARATOR '|')
FROM regions
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Very close to what I need! Is there a way to concatenate with pipes `|` instead of commas, or add a space between states?